# Foreach statement only outputting one record when parsing an XML file

Tags: php, xml, foreach, simplexml

I am trying to parse an XML file so that I get all of the records from the `<pid>` tags that start with a 'b' as shown:

[image]

The link to the `xml` file is:

http://www.bbc.co.uk/radio1/programmes/schedules/england.xml

And the code I have so far is:

```
<?php

$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://www.bbc.co.uk/radio1/programmes/schedules/england.xml');
foreach($xml->day>broadcasts->broadcast as $pid){
echo $pid->programme->pid;
}
?>
```

As far as my knowledge goes, this `foreach statement` should echo out all of the pid records, where it only does the first one.

Any ideas on where my code is going wrong as to how I make it output all of them?

Comment: Did you mean `$xml->day->broadcasts->broadcast`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop needs to go one level deeper, since the `programme` nodes are multiple children of a single `broadcast` node.  You therefore need to loop over all the `programme` nodes in each `broadcast` node to echo out their `pid`

```
foreach($xml->day>broadcasts->broadcast as $broadcast){

  // Loop over all <programme> contained in each <broadcast>
  foreach ($broadcast->programme as $prog) {
    echo $prog->pid;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are iterating over whole xml structure, which contains only one "day" node.

you should position your "cursor" first on the parent of the elements you wish to iterate on :

```
<?php 

$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://www.bbc.co.uk/radio1/programmes/schedules/england.xml');
$broadcasts = $xml->day->broadcasts;
foreach($broadcasts->broadcast as $bc) {
    echo $bc->programme->pid;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, my mistake. I edited my post, though the principle remains the same